# How to express any Unicode character as "\u????" format in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode

I found some nice Unicode characters on a web site that I would like to use in my Ruby program, but they only include the visual character and not the numeric code I would use in the "\u...." form of expressing it. I would prefer to use the "\u1234" form when I specify it in the source code so that any font can display it. How can I derive this "\u..." value from the original character (e.g. "⬆")?

Comment: On most platforms you can put "⬆" directly in your ruby code and it will work fine. No need for mysterious hex codes.

Comment: I said "I would prefer to use the "\u1234" form when I specify it in the source code so that any font can display it." because the \u notation will enable identifying the character, whereas a random placeholder character used for all unknown characters will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numeric string to go after the "\u" can be computed in 2 steps:

1) call `ord` to get the numeric value of the character

2) call `to_s(16)` to convert that to a hex representation

```
[11] pry(main)> '⬆'.ord.to_s(16)
"2b06"
[12] pry(main)> "\u2b06"
"⬆"
```